# i can't run my php code on local hosrt

Tags: php, wamp

I left coding and programming for a while because my laptop broke down. So today, I went back into PHP but the problem here is that I  can't run my code to see the output. The message I keep getting from my browser is "Unable to connect". I went further to check my internet connection to make sure everything was in order and it was. Although I highly suspect that this problem may be arriving from my WAMP server. Please help me out!

Comment: Are you sure your wamp is correctly set? Sometimes skype prevents it from turning itself on proprely. Is the icon green?

Comment: It's http://localhost not http://localhosrt And you don't need an internet connection to see a local website.

Answer (score -1):

One of the first things you should check is whether the WAMP server is attaching to port 80 (standard HTTP port) or not. Typically with dev environments it's actually port 8080 unless configured otherwise.

Try connecting to http://localhost:8080 and see if you can run your application.

If the server does bind to port 80, check that nothing else is using that port. I remember that Skype used to bind to port 80 and would therefore block local webservers from starting processes. I don't know if this is still the case.